# How to say "in my opinion" in chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin

For example, "In my opinion, this music is very good".

The translation indicated by Google, 在我看来, seems rather dodgy to me.

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: But in my understanding, 看来is used more like "it seems" then "i think". O.o And I didn't think "在" could be used like that?

Comment: Agree with congusbongus, it sounds perfect to native Chinese speakers.

Comment: “在我看来” is correct, however you can also say “以我之见”。

Answer (score 7):

我认为，我觉得，依我看，在我看来，依我之见，etc.
In your condition both are okay. But in daily life I would say 我觉得 since it's more common and informal.
窃以为 is an ancient-feel formal word for that , so is 恕我愚见.